# Recovering the textual content of a PDF file with luatex

Tags: luatex, pdf, text, lua

Is it possible, with LuaTeX, to retrieve the textual content of a PDF (using lua code I imagine)? For my purposes, it doesn't have to be "clean" (for example, the order doesn't really have to be respected), it's for "statistics" on the words used.

Comment: you need to navigate pdf internal structure to find and decode text streams but... https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-1/tb109hoekwater.pdf

Comment: it would be a lot easier to call pdftotext and just read the text from lua

Comment: Modern LuaTeX has slightly different interfaces, but it's still pretty similar to the code in the article that David Carlisle linked to. I've actually implemented something pretty similar before, and it's not _quite_ as hard as it looks.

Comment: Thank you. It would be a great package that mimic `pdftotext` from inside `LuaTeX`.